# How to tell if a condition is met within the next n rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that looks like this:

```
event    response
0           5
0           4
1           5
0           6
0           5
0           5
1           5
0           4
0           4
0           4
0           5
0           5
```

If `df.event` indicates `1`, then the event of interest has occurred. If the event occurred, then I want to see what the response is. If the response is a value greater than 5, then I want to flag the response as `True`. Due to a potential time lag, I want to look for `response` values higher than 6 throughout the 3 rows preceding each `event` condition.

It should look like this:

```
event    response      responseType
0           5             False
0           4             False
1           5             False
0           6             True
0           5             False
0           5             False
1           5             False
0           4             False
0           4             False
0           4             False
0           5             False
0           5             False
```

To be clear about the condition:

You can see that the first time `event` is `1`, there is a value greater than `5` in `response` within the 3 rows preceding the event condition, so `True` is labeled at the point this condition is satisfied. For the second time the event condition is met, the response value does not exceed 5 within the next 3 rows of the event condition, so the `responseType` stays False.

Comment: *throughout the 3 rows preceding* seems to contradict with *next n rows* in your title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check current row `response` > 5 and current row and last 2 rows `count` equal 1 by using [`.shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) as follows:

```
df['responseType'] = df['response'].gt(5) & (df['event'].eq(1) |
                                             df['event'].shift(1).eq(1) |
                                             df['event'].shift(2).eq(1))


print(df)

    event  response  responseType
0       0         5         False
1       0         4         False
2       1         5         False
3       0         6          True
4       0         5         False
5       0         5         False
6       1         5         False
7       0         4         False
8       0         4         False
9       0         4         False
10      0         5         False
11      0         5         False
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to checkout `rolling`:

```
df['responseType'] = (df.event.rolling(3).max() == 1) & df.response.gt(5)
```